# Having dedicated instance to handle GET and POST request in node.js

Tags: node.js, url-routing, multiple-instances

I am planning to have 2 node.js instance ( nod1, node2) and trying to handle all the "get" request though node1 and all the "post" request through node2.

Is there a way i can validate if any "post" request comes into node1 , can i redirect that to node2.

Thanks
Siva.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you choose that kind of design?

Comment: Need to have a separate instance to make sure the read instance not getting affected in case of any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup where I use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) module to loadbalance my instances over multiple servers and instances.

You can use the module to forward request based on method.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and update if i face any issues.